# Trouble getting MainActivityContext in Fragment

Tags: android, listview-adapter

I'm pretty new to android programming, i've built a fragment and i'm trying to put the mainactivity context inside of ListViewAdapter but I get an error saying: android.app.activity cannot cannot be applied to android.content.context
I'm not necessarily sure why this is happening in the ListViewAdapter, whereas just below under InputStream there doesn't seem to be a problem.

```
 import android.app.Fragment;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.ListView;

 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.HashMap;

 import Model.Statistics;
 import util.DatabaseHelper;

 import static com.example.sheyda.scorestats.Constants.FIFTH_COLUMN;
 import static com.example.sheyda.scorestats.Constants.FIRST_COLUMN;
 import static com.example.sheyda.scorestats.Constants.FOURTH_COLUMN;
 import static com.example.sheyda.scorestats.Constants.SECOND_COLUMN;
 import static com.example.sheyda.scorestats.Constants.SIXTH_COLUMN;
 import static com.example.sheyda.scorestats.Constants.THIRD_COLUMN;

public class TopFragment extends Fragment {
private InputStreamReader fileReader;
private BufferedReader buffReader;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_f1, container, false);
    ListView listview = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView_SID);
    try {
        populateLV("stats.txt");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), list);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    return v;
}


public void populateLV(String fileName) throws IOException {

    list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    Statistics stat = new Statistics();


    InputStream descriptor = getActivity().getBaseContext().getAssets().open(fileName);
    fileReader = new InputStreamReader(descriptor);
    buffReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    String line;
    // Counter stops at 40 because maximum number of students allowed is 40
    int count = 0;
    while ((line = buffReader.readLine()) != null && count <= 40) {
        String[] l = line.split("~");
        HashMap<String, String> temp = new HashMap<String, String>();
        temp.put(FIRST_COLUMN, l[0]);
        temp.put(SECOND_COLUMN, l[1]);
        temp.put(THIRD_COLUMN, l[2]);
        temp.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, l[3]);
        temp.put(FIFTH_COLUMN, l[4]);
        temp.put(SIXTH_COLUMN, l[5]);
        list.add(temp);
        count++;
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: An Activity is a Context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getActivity()` instead of `getActivity().getBaseContext()` everywhere.